# Loading data in HBox layout, FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am developing a simple app using javafx. I experience one problem. I want to populate my HBox layout with some data, and want to do this in my Controller class. I do not know how to refernce a method inside my Controller class to the element in my FXML file, so that as soon as my app starts, and main window loads, the HBox gets populated with data. Which attribute of HBox element should I use?

Here is some code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<Pane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gui.Controller" >
   <children>
      <HBox layoutX="386.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="371.0" prefWidth="200.0" fx:id="hbox"  />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the `ObservableList` returned by [`Pane.getChildren()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html#getChildren--).